# Upgrade Spotify (spotify-client) on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, spotify

I have Spotify for Linux on ubuntu 14.04 and I would like to update to access the latest features. I have looked online and found nothing. Would this do?:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade spotify-client
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [official PPA](https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/linux/), open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

This is the latest version for Linux and will keep it up to date.